# How to set the one value with where condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe(df) like this

```
   key            name value
0    0          master     0
1    1           basic     0
2    2           clear     0
3    3            debu     0
```

What I want to do is like this below

```
items = [master,master,basic,clear]

for i in items:   # loop the items
    df[where('name==@i')].value += 1     # increment each item
```

Final output should be

```
   key            name value
0    0          master     2
1    1           basic     1
2    2           clear     1
3    3            debu     0
```

How can I fetch the one value and increment ???

Comment: `@i` is a very odd notation. But `df.loc[df['name']==i, 'value']` may get you what you want.

Comment: With pandas, it's recommended to not use `+=`, but something along the lines of `df = df + x` instead. That is, no in-place assignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with `Counter`, then loop is not necessary:

```
from collections import Counter

items = ['master','master','basic','clear']

df['value'] = df['name'].map(Counter(items))
print (df)
   key    name  value
0    0  master      2
1    1   basic      1
2    2   clear      1
3    3    debu      0
```

But it is possible like mentioned in comments filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), in my opinion assign with `+=` is not problem in pandas, be free use it:

```
items = ['master','master','basic','clear']

for i in items:   # loop the items
    df.loc[df['name']==i, 'value'] += 1    

print (df)
   key    name  value
0    0  master      2
1    1   basic      1
2    2   clear      1
3    3    debu      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it but not with as may options as @jezrael

```
items = ['master','master','basic','clear']
l={i:items.count(i) for i in items}
df['value']=df['name'].map(l).fillna(0).astype(int)
df


key name    value
0   0   master  2
1   1   basic   1
2   2   clear   1
3   3   debu    0
```